# Is the SCIM user ID the same as an IdP's setting for a user ID if SCIM is not enabled?

Tags: idp, scim

Say you have an IdP that can act as a SCIM server (WSO2 is one -- I would be interested to know if there are others), but SCIM is not currently enabled and it is up and running for a while with user Fred.  Fred has a user ID of 31415.  Now we decide to enable SCIM on the IdP and a client makes a SCIM query for the users.  Will Fred's ID (prominent in the JSON response) be 31415, or would enabling SCIM have caused the IdP to generate additional/new SCIM IDs for all the users? I know for normal, non-SCIM operations, Fred would still be associated with 31415, but maybe for SCIM operations there would be a new ID.

Answer (score 0):

Either approach would be acceptable. I don't know the specifics of any SCIM servers, libraries, etc on how they'd treat it. For simplicity's sake, if possible I'd recommend representing the existing internal ID value of 31415 and using that for the SCIM ID value as well.

Comment: For a bit of added clarity: My answer was more aligned to what would be acceptable via the standard, as the question isn't specific to a single IDP/library. Also worth keeping in mind that whatever IDP or SCIM server/library may possibly reuse ID values across different object types (i.e.: users vs groups). This isn't allowed in the SCIM standard, as the value for "id" must be unique across all resources.